# Tiny mce line breaks

Tags: javascript, tinymce, line-breaks

I use tiny mce for user to display text. And i use this code to display their text:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function init_ContentSwap() {
    var swap1 = {
        restoreDefault: false,
        content: {
            '1': "[[*tinymcetext]]",
            '2': "[[*tinymcetext]]",
            '3': "[[*tinymcetext]]"

        }
    }

    dw_ContentSwap.setup(swap1);
  }

  dw_Event.add(window, 'load', init_ContentSwap);`    

<div class="code_demo">

  <ul class="demoLinks">
    <li><a href="#1" class="showInfo 1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2" class="showInfo 2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3" class="showInfo 3">3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="infoDiv">[[*tinymcetext]]</div>
</div>


<!-- end demo -->

<p class="clearer">&nbsp;</p>
```

The first problem is when user copy/paste text it create linebreaks in html code and the javascript code dosen't work anymore. In tinymce remove_linebreak is set to yes, and it works but not with pasted text.

The second problem is that i use a template with div in tinymce, and it generates linebreaks in tiny mce when i use it.

And my third problem is that i use " to display text in my javascript but when my user use " in his text it breaks the javascript code. So what is the best way to replace it ??

Comment: you migfht want to have a look at the paste_preprocess - setting of tinymce

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried to look at past_preprocess. But the problem is when i embed a youtube video or a template it createz line breaks in html as well. I just need to find something that completely remove all linebreaks. Thx for your help by the way.

Comment: you can remove them in the function past_preprocess, it is pretty easy

Comment: Ok but i embed video directly with tinymce the same for template so i don't paste anything. I mean as i  use tinymce to do that and it creates line break as well i don't understand how past_preprocess could help. I might be wrong or miss something.

Comment: but you said there woud be pasting and breaks afterwards in the content ('The first problem is when user copy/paste text it create linebreaks in html code')

Comment: Yes, you're right, but on reflection it was not THE real problem. Thank you for your help. The solution was :      tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        apply_source_formatting : false
});   No more line breaks in html code this way.

Comment: than you should post this as an answer and accept it

Comment: this is not a direct answer - but using something designed for code editing might be better than TinyMCE. Like ace editor http://ace.c9.io/#nav=embedding